# How do I split the dataset which has the same ID but different condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to split my dataset into different temp table. The current dataset will have 3 columns includes question, answer and ID. Under Question its always have 3 types: Call type/Date/Other questions. Same for answer: Initial Checking/1-1-2024/Other answers. Here is the example:

| Question | Answer | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Call Type | Initial Checking | 1234 |
| Date | 1/1/2024 | 1234 |
| Whats your name | Mike | 1234 |
| Whats your home | LA | 1234 |
| Call Type | Second Checking | 4567 |
| Date | 5/1/2024 | 4567 |
| Whats your Zip | 55555 | 4567 |
| Whats your City | Miami | 4567 |
| Call Type | Initial Checking | 7891 |
| Date | 4/2/2024 | 7891 |
| Whats your name | Jenny | 7891 |

How do I make a new dataset or temp table to store same catalog answer ( in this case will be Initial checking and Second Checking),

The new dataset will be

| Question | Answer | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Call Type | Initial Checking | 1234 |
| Date | 1/1/2024 | 1234 |
| Whats your name | Mike | 1234 |
| Whats your home | LA | 1234 |
| Call Type | Initial Checking | 7891 |
| Date | 4/2/2024 | 7891 |
| Whats your name | Jenny | 7891 |

| Question | Answer | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Call Type | Second Checking | 4567 |
| Date | 5/1/2024 | 4567 |
| Whats your Zip | 55555 | 4567 |

I have done something like this

```
SELECT R* INTO #INITIAL 
FROM #Result1 R 
WHERE R.Answer = 'Initial Checking'
```

But apparently this is wrong. Should I use PARTITION BY?

Comment: Deciding which table a row belongs in is determined by the existence of an answer  = "Initial Checking" for its ID.  So use : WHERE id in (SELECT id FROM #Result1 WHERE answer ='Initial Checking')

Comment: Why do you think you need temp tables anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * into #Initial 
from #Result1
where id in (Select id from #Result1 where Answer = 'Initial Checking');

select * into #Second
from #Result1 
where id in (Select id from #Result1 where Answer = 'Second Checking');
```